# Security concerns on server-side reading the XML files whcih are uploaded from remote clients

Tags: php, validation, security, ftp, 7zip

I have a project briefly described as follows:

- There is a server which allows clients to upload 7z-compressed files which are expected to contain only XML files. The uploading is via FTP (server-side using FileZilla Server). I have did some basic restriction like enforce firewall rules that only IP's in the white list can do file transfer.
- On scheduled time, the server-side batch script will decompress the 7z files and then some PHP programs will process the XML files.

It works fine so far. But I guess it is lack of security considerations. Is it possible that the PHP program opens some fake XML file which might result in some bad consequence? Or is it possible the 7z files are camouflages of virus or something dangerous, and the decompressing just trigger their malicious behavior? I would like to ask for opionions about how I can validate the files before using them?

Thank you!

Comment: A bit broad, but you would also need to consider about trusting the content of the file.  So at some point you need to trust data being uploaded.  Also make sure you keep the server updated to ensure any vulnerabilities are being protected against.

Comment: Thank you @NigelRen. To add some detail, the OS of the server is Windows Server 2022, and I am always keeping it updated. As to the data-trusting issue I guess it will be a question too. But first I would like to know if the server-side procedure might trigger a bomb while opening the 7z or XML files,.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `fopen` / `fread` / `fclose` / `file_get_contents` only open a file and get the text content. I could not find any CVE's that would convince me otherwise. Therefore, as long as you don't `eval` that content, you're safe to go. But also make sure, your code doesn't fall for a ZIP bomb.

Comment: Thank you @stui for sharing the information. Yes what exactly I am concerned is something bad might happen while using `file_get_contents`. Your opinion comfort me a lot :).  As to the ZIP file, I have an idea that maybe I can schedule Windows Defender to scan the uploaded 7z file before extracting them. If anything malicious is found then remove the file before it is being accessed by 7z..exe. Hope this could lower the risk.